# need to use regex to add to a string while keeping all the words

Tags: sql, regex, replace

I have a sql statement which is about 500000 lines of very repetitive code.

Each line contains something likes this `MYOBJECT1 AS OBJ1` while the next line would have something like `MYOBJECT2 AS OBJ2` and so on for about 50000 times.

I need to cast all of these to `varchars` because some objects are numbers and some are `varchars` and I get an error that my `datatypes must be the same`.

I need to add the cast function to each of these lines for something like this

```
cast(MYOBJECT1 as varchar(100))OBJ1
```

Is this possible because adding this to every line would take me forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace matches of `(\w+) AS (\w+)` with `cast(\1 as varchar(100))\2` where `\1` and `\2` are references to the first and second capturing groups.  Depending on the tool you use you may need to use `$1` and `$2` instead.

Example: http://regex101.com/r/uL4jP4

Comment: you are unbelievable it worked! I can't thank you enough, you saved me weeks of work!